# Merge Sort Algorithm `int object not iterable`

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning about merge sort algorithm on Real Python and came across this implementation that results in **Type error** *int obkect is not iterable*  Any one knows how I can resolve this? I have provided a list *n_array* for testing that the code works.

## Function to merge two different arrays

```
def merge(left, right):

    if len(left)==0:
        return right

    if len(right) == 0:
        return left 

    result =[]

    left_index=right_index=0 

    while len(result) < len(left) + len(right):

        if left[left_index] <= right[right_index]:
            result.append(left[left_index])
            left_index +=1
        else:
            result.append(right[right_index])
            right_index+=1

        if right_index == len(right):
            result +=left[left_index]
            break 

        if left_index == len(left):
            result +=right[right_index]
            break 
    
    return result
```

## Function to recursively split the array into two

```
def merge_sort(array):

    if len(array) < 2:
        return array 

    midpoint = len(array)//2
    return merge(merge_sort(array[:midpoint]),merge_sort(array[midpoint:]))

n_array = [2,5,1,8,6]
result = merge_sort(array=n_array)
print(result)
```

Comment: `result +=left[left_index]` and `result +=right[right_index]` attempt to extend `result` with an `int`. The function `result.__iadd__` requires an iterable argument. Are you looking for `result.append`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if right_index == len(right):
        result +=left[left_index]
        break 

    if left_index == len(left):
        result +=right[right_index]
```

Here you are trying to extend the list. You have to append if you are adding an element in the list.

```
    if right_index == len(right):
        result.append(left[left_index])
        break 

    if left_index == len(left):
        result.append(right[right_index])
```

Also seems some issue with the logic. As some element gets missed.

Comment: Aha! I tried this but my sorted array would leave out the max value.  

```
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```